# cordova: expand and collapse the list only when it is click

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a expand and collapse list which I base on an example https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/accordion-list/2832.

My list is option list to choose and then search. The issue is it will change from expand to collapse when I search. When I search for the second time, it will change from collapse to expand again.

What I want is:

- preset as collapse
- expand and collapse only when it is manually clicked

Below is my html

```
<div class="item" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
     ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
    <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-
           minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col boldText">Investment</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-if="isGroupShown(group)">
        <div class="row centerized">
            <div class="col col-40"></div>
            <div class="col col-30">Min</div><div class="col col-30">Max</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-40">Amount</div>
            <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="0" ng-model="searchQuery.yaMin"></div>
            <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="5" ng-model="searchQuery.yaMax"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
     if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
     } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
     }
   };
   $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
     return $scope.shownGroup === group;
   };
```

Below is the jsddile (first time using)
https://jsfiddle.net/fhmLLa4u/

Comment: Can you add your code in  plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: @RameshRajendran add the jsfiddle, but unable to show the plus and minus sign. May be my code is in ionic